# mobilefirst push notification change android app_name

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Hello im working in a mobilefirst 6.3 hybrid app, and i have a problem when changing the app_name from my string.xml.

i have my hybrid name app `<string name="app_name">ASDFGHJK</string>`and i nee to change that to `<string name="app_name">ASDF GHJK</string>`, when ive change de app_name:

when the app is in the background, the click on the push doesnt do anything, and when im in the app, the receiver method doesnt trigger, how can a chage my app name witout having this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app_name` value in res\values\strings.xml is used internally to create Intent objects. So when the app is closed and the GCMIntentService receives a message, it creates an intent with the action as `<packagename>.<app_name>` and send it to notification service to show the notification in the notifications bar.

This is the intent name as used in AndroidManifest.xml to indicate that app has to be launched on tapping the notification:

```
<activity android:name=".PushNotifications" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="sensor"> 
    ....
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="com.PushNotifications.PushNotifications.NOTIFICATION"/>  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
    </intent-filter>
```

So now if the `app_name` is changed to any other string, internally the Intent will be created as `com.PushNotifications.<new_name>`.
But the AndroidManifest.xml still has for example `com.PushNotifications.PushNotifications` (in the case of the sample application), so the app is not getting launched as the intent action is different.

To display the application with a different name, follow these steps:

1. In strings.xml, add an additional  new_name_value
2. In AndroidManifest.xml , modify the label with the new string name

   ```
   <application android:label="@string/app_new_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon"> 
   <activity android:name=".PushNotifications" android:label="@string/app_new_name"...
   ```

Comment: that doesnt change my icon name on my app and the app title when im going to the background

Comment: This process seems to be causing us trouble, we rename the manifest package a build time.  But Push fails to start because it uses context and tries to get the app_name from the wrong place.